# saveData method saves twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a React app that includes one separate component for CRUD functionality of Products and another separate component for CRUD functionality of Suppliers.

I am using the same saveData method for both components (the Create functionality of CRUD.. that is triggered when the User presses Save after filling in the input fields of Product or Supplier). The saveData method is located in a central ProductsAndSuppliers.js file that is available to both the Products and Supplier components.

In both of the Product & Supplier components, there is a table showing the Products or Suppliers already present as dummy data.
I made a button at the bottom of each page to add a new Product or Supplier... depending on which tab the user has selected on the left side of the screen (Product or Supplier).

Since I am using the same saveData method in both cases, I have the same problem whenever I try to add a new Product or Supplier to each respective table after filling out the input fields. My new Product or Supplier is added.. but twice and I can't figure out why.

I have tried using a spread operator to add the new item to the collection but am having no success:

```
  saveData = (collection, item) => {
    if (item.id === "") {
      item.id = this.idCounter++;
      this.setState((collection) => {
        return { ...collection, item }
      })
    } else {
      this.setState(state => state[collection]
        = state[collection].map(stored =>
          stored.id === item.id ? item : stored))
    }
  }
```

Here is my original saveData method that adds the new Product or Supplier, but twice:

```
  saveData = (collection, item) => {
    if (item.id === "") {
      item.id = this.idCounter++;
       this.setState(state => state[collection]
         = state[collection].concat(item));
    } else {
      this.setState(state => state[collection]
        = state[collection].map(stored =>
          stored.id === item.id ? item : stored))
    }
  }
```

**my state looks like this:**

```
this.state = {
  products: [
    { id: 1, name: "Kayak", category: "Watersports", price: 275 },
    { id: 2, name: "Lifejacket", category: "Watersports", price: 48.95 },
    { id: 3, name: "Soccer Ball", category: "Soccer", price: 19.50 },
  ],
  suppliers: [
    { id: 1, name: "Surf Dudes", city: "San Jose", products: [1, 2] },
    { id: 2, name: "Field Supplies", city: "New York", products: [3] },
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are issues with both of your implementations.

Starting with the top one:

```js
// don't do this
this.setState((collection) => {
   return { ...collection, item }
})
```

In this case, `collection` is your component state and you're adding a property called `item` to it. You're going to get this as a result:

```js
{
  products: [],
  suppliers: [],
  item: item
}
```

The correct way to do this with the spread operator is to return an object that represents the state update. You can use a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names) to target the appropriate collection:

```js
this.setState((state) => ({
    [collection]: [...state[collection], item]
  })
)
```

<sub>* Note that both this and the example below are using the [implicit return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#function_body) feature of arrow functions. Note the parens around the object.</sub>

---

In the second code sample you're

1. mutating the existing state directly which you **should not do**.
2. returning an array instead of a state update object.

```js
// don't do this
this.setState(state =>
  state[collection] = state[collection].concat(item)
);
```

Assignment expressions return the assigned value, so this code returns an array instead of an object and I'd frankly be surprised if this worked at all.

The correct implementation is the same as above except it uses concat instead of spread to create the new array:

```js
this.setState(state => ({
    [collection]: state[collection].concat(item)
  })
);
```

---

#### needlessly fancy, arguably silly id generators:

```js
const nextId = (function idGen (start = 100) {
  let current = start;
  return () => current++;
})(100);

console.log(nextId()); // 100
console.log(nextId()); // 101
console.log(nextId()); // 102

// ----------------

// a literal generator, just for fun
const ids = (function* IdGenerator(start = 300) {
  let id = start;
  while (true) {
    yield id++;
  }
})();

console.log(ids.next().value); // 300
console.log(ids.next().value); // 301
console.log(ids.next().value); // 302
```

Comment: thanks a lot. do you know how I could get the id of the new item to increment from the last product/supplier id in the array?
in my constructor under this.state I have a variable this.idCounter=100; not listed above which just sets the new item to equal 100 for now. 
The first item added is id 100, and if I add another it is id 101... but ideally I would like to continue incrementing from the last added id in the product or suppliers array

Comment: If this is a real app with persistent storage you'd generally let the backend generate the new item id because the browser doesn't necessarily have the latest information. If you want to do it on the client for whatever reason, you could have an IdGenerator that spits out a new id every time you call it. If you needed it to be sequential and contiguous for some reason you could either keep track of the last used ID and increment it (which is basically what you're doing now) or you could figure it out with Math.max() on the current ids, but that seems unnecessary for something you already know.

Comment: Updated my answer with a couple of arguably silly id generators.